# Cannot print anymore since upgrade to Macos 10.13.6

Tags: high-sierra, printing, cups

I was using Macos 10.13.4.

When I upgraded to Macos 10.13.6, I noticed my print jobs got stuck in the print queue so I deleted those print jobs and then I installed a newer version of the printer driver from Ricoh: http://support.ricoh.com/bb/html/dr_ut_e/rc3/model/mpc3004ex/mpc3004ex.htm

and I recreated a new printer called Test1.

Now, I can print some small pdf files but I cannot print this 45 page pdf file: https://eprint.iacr.org/2018/053.pdf because the print job is stuck from half an hour :

Cups says this on http://localhost:631/printers/Test1 :

```
Test1-536   Unknown     Withheld    3550k   Unknown     processing since
Fri Jul 27 13:17:17 2018 
"Copying print data."
```

```bash
$ lpr -P Test1 053.pdf
$ lpq -P Test1 +2
Test1 is ready and printing
Rank    Owner   Job     File(s)                         Total Size
active  mansfel 536     053.pdf                         3635200 bytes
Test1 is ready and printing
Rank    Owner   Job     File(s)                         Total Size
active  mansfel 536     053.pdf                         3635200 bytes
Test1 is ready and printing
Rank    Owner   Job     File(s)                         Total Size
active  mansfel 536     053.pdf                         3635200 bytes
....
```

Can you help me ?

EDIT1 : Cups WebInterface is enabled

EDIT2 : The job is stuck for half an hour :

```bash
$ time lpq -P Test1 +2
Test1 is ready and printing
Rank    Owner   Job     File(s)                         Total Size
active  mansfel 536     053.pdf                         3635200 bytes
Test1 is ready and printing
Rank    Owner   Job     File(s)                         Total Size
active  mansfel 536     053.pdf                         3635200 bytes
Test1 is ready and printing
Rank    Owner   Job     File(s)                         Total Size
active  mansfel 536     053.pdf                         3635200 bytes
....
Test1 is ready and printing
Rank    Owner   Job     File(s)                         Total Size
active  mansfel 538     053.pdf                         3635200 bytes
Test1 is ready and printing
lpq: Undefined error: 0

real    29m4.571s
user    0m4.278s
sys     0m4.707s
```

EDIT3 : Test1 is connected to a Ricoh MP C3004ex printer via the lpd protocol.

EDIT4 : Cups GUI (http://localhost:631/) listens to the ipp port but not the printer server (x.y.z.t) :

```
$ netcat -v -z -w 5 x.y.z.t 631
islande [x.y.z.t] 631 (ipp): Operation timed out
```

The printer server (x.y.z.t) listens on the LPD port :

```
$ netcat -v -z -w 5 x.y.z.t 515
islande [x.y.z.t] 515 (printer) open
```

EDIT5: I need to check my loptions, but I cannot do this because I don't have the MacBook anymore as my internship is finished.

Comment: Is cups installed as part of the ricoh PPD driver on the page you listed?

Comment: @Scottmeup Can you be a little more specific ? How can I check that ?

Comment: Ummm, CUPS is part of the default installation of *ALL* macOS versions. On more recent versions you had to enable the CUPS web server (GUI) with this terminal command: cupsctl WebInterface=yes

Comment: @SteveChambers I enabled Cups WebInterface for quite some time now

Comment: @SteveChambers I'd like to understand why CUPS is being used rather than a native print driver if there's a problem with it. I could be mistaken of course, but I'm not confident that the inclusion of CUPS with the operating system negates the ability of a vendor's software package to offer installation or enablement of a version of it rather than providing a native driver. I'd be interest if you were able to confirm this? SebMa are there print drivers available to you other than CUPS after you install the driver package from the ricoh page you listed? If so, is there a requirement to use CUPS?

Comment: CUPS is nothing more than a detailed view into the Mac printing subsystem. macOS uses CUPS to print. That command just enables the original UNIX management GUI. So any macOS printer driver is, for all intents and purposes, a CUPS printer driver and therefore *IS* a "native" printer driver.

Comment: What printer are you trying to print to (model)? How are you connected to the printer (network/usb/...)? Does the printer have onboard memory, if so how much? Is the printer correctly identified in the Printers & Scanners PrefPane? The above information shows that things aren't happening, but nothing about your actual printer and configuration.

Comment: @sdmeyers I'm using the lpd protocol to print to a Ricoh MP C3004ex printer.

Comment: So did you manually configure the printer? Why? Does it not show up automatically in the printer browser? Did you try IPP printing rather then LPD? Also this printer should just show up as a Bonjour printer in the Printer Preference unless there are some networking shenanigans going on. Sounds like you are making this way more difficult then it needs to be.

Comment: @sdmeyers Because the university print server to which this printer is connected does not listen to the IPP 631 port and that the print server does not provide something else. What's wrong with LPD anyway ? Before the upgrade, it was working like a charm.

Comment: "Cups says this on http://localhost:631/printers/Test1 :" Umm, that sounds like IPP to me. LPD Generally uses port 515. Uninstall the printer and try to re-add it using the Printers and Scanners Preferences. Also some Universities require special software to access there printers, so I'd check with the IT folks there.

Comment: @sdmeyers Please see my new EDIT4

Answer (score 2):

I had kind of the same issue with an epson printer, and I tried several times to make it work by downloading driver from different websites with non results. The solution is downloading even an "old" drive from the apple support website https://support.apple.com/downloads/drivers and It really does work. I wasn't really sure at first because it didn't said that support Mac Sierra but in the end it worked perfectly!!!

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot test your solution because I don't have my MacBook Air anymore because my internship is finished. Thanks for your answer :-)